# Find change in value in a row and append to new data frame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do you get Pandas to skim through a column and append the the row before a change in values is observed?

I need to go through a column and append the data from the row before the value switches in that column.

for instance I have an ID of a203.  I want to pull the last a203 before the the value in that column switches to a251.  This will give me the max tumor volume recorded for that ID.

I did this before using VBA and it was this formula but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in Pandas/Python

VBA it would be

for i 1 to LR

if cells (i+1,1).value <> cells(i,1).value then

I tried to figure it out on my own but the best I can come up with is

final_vol_df = pd.DataFrame()

for tumor_sorted_mouse["Mouse ID"].shift() != tumor_sorted_mouse["Mouse ID"]:

but I can't seem to figure out how to make it the same as the equation I used in VBA.

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL3sd.png)
```

Comment: df.sort_values(“tumor_volume”).groupby(“mouse_id”).tail(1)